# Why can't both Gradle sync and internal http work in a fresh install of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, windows-10

I'm trying to install and start learning Android Development. I have tried a lot of things to get Android Studio working, but I simply can't!

There are 2 errors:

> Gradle 'MyFirstApp' project refresh failed - Error:Protocol family
>   unavailable

and

> Internal HTTP server disabled: Cannot start internal HTTP server. Git
>   integration, JavaScript debugger and LiveEdit may operate with errors.
>   Please check your firewall settings and restart Android Studio

Here what I already did:

For Gradle:

1. tried to uninstall deleting all folders and files regarding AS 1.5.1 and reinstall
2. checked for java environment variables
3. reinstall just gradle

For Internal HTTP:

1. disabled Kaspersky Internet Security (version 16.0.0.614(d))
2. checked if any other service or software could be using some known ports, disabled as much as I could
3. uninstall and try a fresh install as I did for gradle

Nothing works!

I always install with Kaspersky temporaly disabled and I run the installation package as administrator

Some data that might be useful:

- SO: Windows 10 Pro (single language en-us)
- Android Studio: 1.5.1 (android-studio-bundle-141.2456560-windows)

What else do you need?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:**

I have just installed on another computer running Windows 10 (home) 64bit with Java JDK 1.8 U 66 just like the first attempt, i.e., with both firewall & anti-virus software disabled and with administrator privileges.

The problem is exactly the same.

:(

Comment: "Cannot start internal HTTP server" sounds like a permissions issue with the user that AS is running on. What platform is this installed on? And does the user that starts AS have permissions to starts services on the machine?

Comment: Hi @Jim, I'm facing the problem even running AS as Administrator. I'm trying to run in a Windows 10 Pro 64bit plataform.